# How to represent NULL selector in Swift

Tags: xcode, swift

When I try to remove all associated actions using the function `.removeTarget(nil, action: NULL, forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.AllEvents)`

I realized that you cant use `NULL`. Then what to use here?

Thank you very much!

Comment: This link might help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27467172/swift-button-removetarget-for-all-action-in-view

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me :

```
Selector(String())
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).

Answer (score 0):

`NULL` selector can be constructed with `nil`:

```
let sel:Selector = nil
```

or `Selector()`.

So you can:

```
.removeTarget(nil, action: nil, forControlEvents: .AllEvents)
// OR
.removeTarget(nil, action: Selector(), forControlEvents: .AllEvents)
```

Comment: Yup. The first one works because the `Selector` type adopts the `NilLiteralConvertible` protocol. I'd advise against the second syntax. Even though it works, it's much less semantically clear to a reader of your code what it means. (It's sort of like writing `Int()` when you mean zero.)